# Show field history on Accounts page

Tags: sales-cloud

I am working on a SalesCloud application for a non-profit. In the Accounts there are 2 custom fields, Amount Fundraised (by that account) and # of Coats Shipped (to that account). These numbers change annually, and I'd like to keep track of the changes year-to-year on the account page. I've already set these fields to track history in Setup->Customize->Accounts->Fields, but I can't figure out if I can show this history on the Accounts page.  Is this possible? Also, I've looked but couldn't find any information on how long this information is kept for.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the field history as a related list by adding it to the account page layout (if you have enabled field history it should show up as one of the related lists when editing the page layout).

SF's field history policy was actually changed in spring 13. From the release notes:

> Salesforce.com has changed its policy on how long you can store field
>   history data. Field history data does not count against your
>   organization’s storage limit, however, Salesforce deletes field history
>   data that is 18 months or older for organizations created after 12:00
>   A.M. on June 2, 2011. You can request disabling of the auto-delete
>   mechanism by contacting salesforce.com support. There is no
>   user-enabled method for turning the delete mechanism on or off.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Go to any record in the account click on edit layout( If you are a system admin you can see this option)

From the left side options click on "Related List" you should be able to see/search for Account history add it to the layout. click save

you should be able to see the history changes in the related list down below.

The history tracking is available for all salesforce objects and can be added through the pagelayout if not enabled by default